# Doctrine ODM / MongoDB: How to query for references within embedded documents?

Tags: mongodb, doctrine, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

I'm new to Doctrine ODM and i'm totally stuck with a simple query :(

Let me start with the document structure:

```
Array
(
[_id] => 4ee1e4527f749c9411000012
[voteList] => Array
    (
        [_id] => 4ee1e4527f749c9411000013
        [votes] => Array
            (
               ... stripped ...
            )
        [latest] => Array
            (
                [_id] => 4ee1e4527f749c9411000014
                [rating] => 1
                [voter] => Array
                    (
                        [$ref] => Voter
                        [$id] => 4ee1e4527f749c941100000f
                        [$db] => x_test
                    )

            )
    )
    ... stripped ...
)
```

This document is called **Voting**.

My Question is, **how to find *Voting*-documents by a particular *voter* (which is stored in *voteList.latest.voter*)**.

I tried it like this:

```
$builder
    ->field('voteList.latest.voter')->references($voter)
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

And this way also:

```
$result = $builder
    ->field('voteList.latest.voter.$id')->equals(new \MongoId($voter->getId()))
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

Both are leading to this exception:

```
Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\MongoDBException: No mapping found for field 'voteList.latest.voter' in class 'App\BaseBundle\Document\Voting'.
```

**Am i building the query incorrectly or might something be wrong with my document classes?**

Thanks for reading, any advices appreciated.

EDIT: Documents attached

```
    /**
     * @ODM\Document(repositoryClass="App\BaseBundle\Document\VotingRepository")
     */
    class Voting
    {
        /**
         * @ODM\Id
         * @var int
         */
        protected $id;

        /**
         * @ODM\EmbedOne(targetDocument="App\BaseBundle\Document\VoteList")
         * @var VoteList
         */
        protected $voteList;

        public function __construct()
        {
            if ($this->voteList === null) {
                $this->voteList = new VoteList();
            }
        }

        /**
         * @return string
         */
        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }

        /**
         * @return VoteList
         */
        public function getVoteList()
        {
            return $this->voteList;
        }
    }
    ;

    /**
     * @ODM\EmbeddedDocument
     */
    class VoteList implements \Countable, \ArrayAccess, \IteratorAggregate
    {
        /**
         * @ODM\Id
         */
        protected $id;

        /**
         * @ODM\EmbedMany(targetDocument="App\BaseBundle\Document\Vote")
         * @var Vote[]
         */
        protected $votes = array();

        /**
         * @ODM\EmbedOne(targetDocument="App\BaseBundle\Document\Vote")
         * @var Vote
         */
        protected $latest;

        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }

        /**
         * @return Vote
         */
        public function getLatest()
        {
            return $this->latest;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @ODM\EmbeddedDocument
     */
    class Vote
    {
        /**
         * @ODM\Id
         */
        protected $id;

        /**
         * @ODM\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="App\BaseBundle\Document\Voter")
         * @var Voter
         */
        public $voter;

        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }

        public function getVoter()
        {
            return $this->voter;
        }

        public function setVoter(Voter $voter)
        {
            $this->voter = $voter;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should post the code of both your documents to give us a more complete picture.

Comment: @elnur thanks for your comment. Edit: Added Documents, stripped down to referencing / embedding stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out it's not working due to a doctrine-odm bug.

https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/pull/207

Comment: looks like it has been fixed now

Comment: The linked issue does not seem to directly address the OP's problem, and the problem still exists in the latest version.

Comment: Actually i've given up working with doctrine ODM except for one project.. in contrary to ORM its way too much beta and i don't see it will reach a really stable state soon.